# How to create a table with three vertical dots in the middle?

Tags: tables, math-operators

I want to create this table in LaTeX but I don't know how to add the three dots in the middle.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: $\vdots$ in every column.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know what for is the fourth column in the tabular in your comment, but I have preserved it in my hint.

```
\documentclass{article}
 
 \begin{document}
 
 \begin{tabular}{l|l|ll} 
 \cline{1-3} State & Action & Value & \\ 
 \cline{1-3} 
 $s_1$ & $a_1$ & $Q(s_1,a_1)_1$ & \\ 
 \cline{1-3} 
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\vdots$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\vdots$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\vdots$} & \\ \cline{1-3}
  & & & \\ 
  \cline{1-3}
   \end{tabular} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @Przemysław Scherwentke answer (+1), but with use of the `tblr` of the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

 \begin{document}
    \begin{center}
 \begin{tblr}{colspec={ *{3}{Q[c, mode=math, wd=5em]} },
              row{1} = {mode=text, l},
              hline{1-3, Y-Z} = {solid},
              vline{2-Y} = {1-2, Z}{solid},
              }   
 State  & Action    & Value         \\
 s_1    & a_1       & Q(s_1,a_1)_1  \\
\SetRow{font=\Huge, rowsep=3ex}
 \vdots & \vdots    & \vdots        \\
  s_n    & a_n       & Q(s_n,a_n)_n \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]